# Loop through vector in as3 to left and to right

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Hei guys, i got stuck here... I have a Vector with 6 elements.All elements are hidden initialy and i show then only element on position 3 like so :

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randomizedTexts[i].alpha = 0;
}

var itemLookingFor = randomizedTexts[randomizedTexts.length - 3];
itemLookingFor.alpha = 1;
```

All good, but... i added events for two arrows (left and right) :

```
leftArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLeft);
rightArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight);
```

In goLeft and goRight function i need the element on position 3 to be displayed and if i press left to display randomizedArray[3] - 1 till randomizedArray[0] and for right to display randomizedArray[3] + 1 till randomizedArray[5].

**I need to mention that my array is shuffled!!!**

What i have tryed:

```
private function goRight(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                randomizedTexts[i].alpha = 0;
            }
            var toRight:Number = 3;
            toRight++;
            trace(toRight);
            randomizedTexts[toRight].alpha = 1;
        }
```

I know isn't good coz everytime goRight function is accesed var toRight is set to 3 :( .

Once again, if i wasn't clear... I got Shuffled array, i hide all elements and display element from array on position 3 and i got 2 arrows to loop through array to left and to right starting from array[3]. What i try to achieve is how to loop to left and to right. Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have, you need to have a few more variables that track the goLeft and goRight position. You should also make a separate function to zero out all the alphas. Every time your goLeft or goRight function is called it will iterate up or down the index it should target.

```
var leftPosition: int;
var rightPosition: int;
var centerPosition: int; // this can be used if you want your center position to be dynamic
var randomizedTexts: Array;
var itemLookingFor: Sprite;

init();

private function init() {
    centerPosition = 3;  // Change this number if you switch to something dynamic
    rightPosition = centerPosition + 1;
    leftPosition = centerPostion - 1;
    leftArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLeft);
    rightArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goRight);
    itemLookingFor = randomizedTexts[centerPosition];
    zeroAlphas();
}

private function zeroAlphas():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < randomizedTexts.length; i++) {
        randomizedTexts[i].alpha = 0;
    }
}

private function goRight(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(rightPosition < randomizedTexts.length -1) {
        randomizedTexts[rightPosition++].alpha = 1;
    }
}

private function goLeft(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(leftPosition > 0) {
        randomizedTexts[leftPosition--].alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: using Vector.indexOf requires less code and less member variables. Also it is pointless to use vector when you don't make the effort to strong type your variables.